# The jQuery Metadata Plugin is deprecated. What is the alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read at http://blog.jquery.com/2011/04/16/official-plugins-a-change-in-the-roadmap/ the following announcement:

> The Metadata plugin will be deprecated, in favor of similar functionality provided by jQuery 1.4.3 and above.

What is the

> similar functionality

that jQuery provides as an alternative from version 1.4.3 and on?

Comment: I'm not sure what functionality you're referring to as 1.4.3 is almost 8 years out of date. Presumably you need the `data()` method instead: http://api.jquery.com/data

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am referring to this statement I referenced: "The Metadata plugin will be deprecated, in favor of similar functionality provided by jQuery 1.4.3 and above." I refer to the substitute of the Metadata plugin. It is deprecated, so what is the native option now instead of the Metedata plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to the latest version of jQuery available but kept this deprecated Metadata plugin in my code. I removed the jQuery Migrate plugin from my code and everything works correctly, meaning that even though the Metadata plugin is officially deprecated, it does not use jQuery code or methods that are incompatible with the latest version of jQuery.